# How can I run dotnet CLI commands inside a running container?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, dockerfile, entity-framework-migrations, debian-buster

I have a running container called tami-app. The Dockerfile is based on a .NET 5 SDK:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /Tami.Operations.Api

COPY src/Tami.Operations.Domain/Tami.Operations.Domain.csproj /Tami.Operations.Domain/
COPY src/Tami.Operations.Api/Tami.Operations.Api.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

COPY src/Tami.Operations.Domain /Tami.Operations.Domain
COPY src/Tami.Operations.Api .

RUN dotnet build -c Release
RUN dotnet publish -c Release --no-build -o /Tami.Operations.Api/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /Tami.Operations.Api
COPY --from=build /Tami.Operations.Api/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Tami.Operations.Api.dll"]
```

I would like to enter the terminal to run .NET CLI commands such as `dotnet ef migrations`. So I type `docker exec -it tami-app bash` and a bash terminal prompt shows up. I then type `dotnet --info` and it tells me that no SDKs installed.

I would like to use the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` as part of the container, how do I do that?

I would like to use the dotnet CLI tool to run migrations.

Comment: So the *real* question is how to run EF migrations inside a container. The Dockerfile *already* runs a dotnet command with `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Tami.Operations.Api.dll"]`. That runs `dotnet Tami.Operations.Api.dll`. The final image is based on ` mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0`, not `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply Entity Framework migrations when using ASP.Net Core in a Docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970148/apply-entity-framework-migrations-when-using-asp-net-core-in-a-docker-image)

Comment: Why not apply the migrations from the application itself? You don't need the SDK to do that

Comment: You have a multi-stage Dockerfile. The mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 image is used, yes. But it's only used as stage in the overall build. The final image is based on mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 which, by definition, does not include the SDK. BTW, .NET 5 is EOL since May 2022 which means these Docker images haven't been updated since that time. They likely contain a lot of vulnerabilities.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Right that is the real question. I understand what you say that the SDK is not installed as part of the final image, and no, the linked post does not answer my Q. I added those lines of code but when I run docker compose, there are no migrations, even though I changed the model

Comment: Can't the Docker GUI for Windows give you a CLI to the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dotnet tools must be installed inside the Dockerfile. The following worked for me:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0
WORKDIR /app

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.17

ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

EXPOSE 8010
```

Answer (score 0):

To open a terminal to your Docker container, you can use [Docker Desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/)

[image: Open terminal for Docker Container]

Comment: I know how to get to the terminal, my Q is how to run dotnet commands when .NET SDK is not installed.